# Retrieve schema name from view definition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I retrieve different views with the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "myDatabase"."mySchema"."VIEWS"
```

That returns a table with these columns notably:

```
TABLE_ID
TABLE_NAME
TABLE_SCHEMA_ID
TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_CATALOG_ID
TABLE_CATALOG
TABLE_OWNER
VIEW_DEFINITION
```

For each `VIEW_DEFINITION` column entries, I am trying to extract all the strings `<Schema_Name>.<View_Name>` (or at least the `<Schema_Name>`).

Is it possible to do that with a SQL query (or by any other way)?

---

**Edit**

The table I obtain using the initial query is as follows:

| TABLE_ID | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA_ID | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_CATALOG_ID | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_OWNER | VIEW_DEFINITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | MY_TABLE_NAME | 99 | MY_TABLE_SCHEMA | 20 | PMY_TABLE_CATALOG | MY_OWNER_VIEWS_ADMIN | … |

where the `VIEW_DEFINITION` column contains queries like the one below:

```sql
"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW My_Table_Schema_VIEWS.My_Table_Name AS
WITH STUDY_SITE_SCOPE AS (
SELECT
    ...
FROM (
       SELECT
          A.SUBJECT_NUMBER
        , A.SUBJECT_STATUS
       FROM <Schema_Name>.<View_Name_1> X
       JOIN <Schema_Name>.<View_Name_2> Y
       ...
     )
JOIN (
       SELECT
          ...
       FROM <Schema_Name>.<View_Name_3> X
       JOIN <Schema_Name>.<View_Name_4> Y
         ...
      )
..."
```

From this `VIEW_DEFINITION` I am trying to extract all the `<Schema_Name>.<View_Name_XX>` strings (or at least the `<Schema_Name>`).

Comment: Could you please add input and desired output data? This would help to understand your goals better.

Comment: @Marcel see edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`information_schema.tables`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html):

```
select t.*
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_type = 'VIEW'
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not see anything related to schema name in the output of your command.

Comment: @6PO0222 . . . It is called `TABLE_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get all base schemas your current view is built on top of.

To answer your question short: Yes, it is.

Maybe the following procedure is giving you an idea on how to solve it via SQL or a Stored Procedure:

1. Query the view definition
2. Search for all strings within the view definition that follow the "FROM" or "JOIN" clause
3. Extract them and probably check for the database name in front of the schema name

Comment: Yes, exactly. My question is how to do the steps 2 and 3.